# Windows 10 "PC wakes up automatically when pressing sleep." Then to activate sleep again for it to really Sleep

Tags: windows-10, sleep, power-management

Activating sleep for the first time, the PC shuts down. When it shuts down, it will automatically start. Fans go fast then go to its normal speed. Then Log in screen activates. Any reason why it is doing this?

I need to activate again the sleep mode. This time PC finally sleeps.

I installed ubuntu and doing the suspend/sleep. It do it flawlessly.

I have this  commands for diagnosing.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Use the Manufacturer's Driver Update App and update BIOS and Power Management drivers

Comment: Updated all my bios and drivers. What do you mean power management drivers?

Comment: The Power Driver should have been part of your update. Power Drives affect proper suspending.

Comment: I see on the laptops they have like dell power drivers etc. This is a PC so I really don't know if there is something like that.

Comment: There may not be and in that case for a desktop, BIOS is usually enough for suspend to work. There may be some other issue with your OS requiring a Repair Install.

Comment: I disabled the wake property on the HID keyboard and it seems fix the problem. maybe my keyboard is broken? I am still observing it before putting it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do a power "powercfg -devicequery wake_armed" in the command prompt. This will list the devices that you need to disable from awake in the device manager.

In this scenario one of the HID keyboard is the culprit. When I disabled it, the problem stops.

The final fix is to uninstall the HID device that cause the error in the device manager. And then scan for hardware changes to reinstall the HID device.